# Print only those numbers that are double of another number in the array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I'm practicing algorithms and let's say we have an array with elements `2, 3, 9, 12, 7, 18`, then **I want to print 18 only because it's double of 9**. When I print the result it always displays much more lines, however, the printed numbers (if there are any) are good. How can I manage displaying the result properly? (Using only arrays.) I know it's a silly question but I tried so many ways and it was only worse.

Now, it shows me this for example (140 is correct, but the other line are not needed):

```
The following number is doubled of another number from the array: 0
The following number is doubled of another number from the array: 0
The following number is doubled of another number from the array: 140
The following number is doubled of another number from the array: 0
The following number is doubled of another number from the array: 0
```

My code:

```
public class DoubleNums {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random random = new Random();

        int[] array = new int[50];
        int[] even;
        int[] doubleNum;
        int count = 0;
        int doubles = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = random.nextInt(200);
            System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) { 
            even = new int[array.length];
            if (array[j] % 2 == 0) {
                even[count] = array[j];
                count++;
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
                doubleNum = new int[array.length];
                if (array[j] / 2 == array[k]) {
                    even[doubles] = k;
                    doubles++;
                    System.out.println("The following number is doubled of another number from the array: " + even[doubles]);               
                }                
            }               
        }
        System.out.println("Number of even nums: " + count);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should check that `j` does not equal `k`. Also, you can reuse the name `i` in your second for-loop (the outer one)

Comment: You are using 'array[j] / 2 == array[k]' as a condition. Since everything there is an integer, remember that 5/2 == 2, so it might be best to use 'array[j] = (array[k] * 2)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw that you asked for a solution that started with your own code...

> I know it's faster but I assumed that we can find a solution using my
>   code with some minor changes.

So I tried to understand what you were trying to do and I have not been able to decipher your method so starting from your *macro* I created a clearer version.

---

### Changes

- I used an ArrayList (`list`) as support instead of your array
  (`even`). The `List` is very convenient in your case because it has the `contains()` function and also its size is variable.
- I took an even number in the array and looked for if there was at least one "half" of it.

---

### Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();

    int[] array = new int[20];
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int evenNumber = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = random.nextInt(100);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // If I found an even number and this is NOT already in the list then I'll study it
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0 && !list.contains(array[i])) {
            evenNumber = array[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                // I add "evenNumber" to the list only if at least one its "half" exist in the array
                if (array[j] * 2 == evenNumber) {
                    list.add(evenNumber);
                    // I dont need to search more, I already found its "half"!
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Doubled nums: " + list);
}
```

### Sample output

```
[71, 88, 45, 97, 64, 31, 54, 12, 14, 86, 22, 42, 35, 44, 70, 65, 93, 85, 99, 14]
Doubled nums: [88, 44, 70]
```

Comment: Hey @Alberto! This is the best solution so far for me (+1). But I don't want to use `List` as I didn't use it in my code above, only arrays. I know it's silly but I'm practicing arrays now (it was out of my scope so far and I want to understand the logic better behind the arrays). I can reproduce this exercise too using other methods but now I want to use only the arrays for this approach.

Answer (score 7):

Use a `HashSet<Integer>` to store double the value of each element:

```
Set<Integer> setOfArray = new HashSet<>();
for (int a : array) setOfArray.add(2 * a);
```

Then loop through the array again, looking for matching elements:

```
for (int a : array) {
  if (setOfArray.contains(a)) {
    System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```

Or

```
IntStream.of(array).boxed().filter(setOfArray::contains)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Won't integer division cause this to mishandle odds? Maybe require a % 2 == 0 in the condition.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the simplicity (+1), I know it's faster but I assumed that we can find a solution using my code with some minor changes.

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple task: first, for each number **n**, store **2n** in a set. Then, iterate through the numbers and check which of them is in the set.

```
import java.util.*;

public class DoubleNums {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = new int[]{2, 3, 9, 12, 7, 18};   //original array

        HashSet<Integer> h = new HashSet<Integer>();     //set

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) h.add(numbers[i] * 2);
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            if(h.contains(numbers[i])) System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Complexity: O(n)**

A `HashSet<Integer>` works like a simple set, but faster, because it uses properties of hash tables to add and find elements.

Answer (score 1):

## Binary search on sorted array

Another approach is to sort the array ([`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D,int,int))), then perform a binary search repeatedly ([`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int%5B%5D,int,int,int))).

I am not sure if this might or might not be faster than hashing approach in other Answers.

Using [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D,int,int)) alters the original array. So copy the array first if that matters to you.

To make the binary search a bit quicker, specify a subrange of the array.

```
// int streamSize = 6, randomNumberOrigin = 1, randomNumberBound = 18;
// Half-Open: Origin is inclusive, Bound is exclusive.
// int[] ints =
//        ThreadLocalRandom
//            .current()
//            .ints( streamSize , randomNumberOrigin , randomNumberBound )
//            .toArray();

int[] ints = { 2, 3, 9, 12, 7, 18 } ;

System.out.println( "array = " + Arrays.toString( ints ) );

Arrays.sort( ints );
List < Integer > doubledNumbers = new ArrayList <>();
int index = 0;
for ( int anInt : ints )
{
    int doubled = ( anInt * 2 );
    // Javadoc: binarySearch​ (int[] a , int fromIndex , int toIndex ,
    // int key ). First element inclusive, last element exclusive.
    int position = Arrays.binarySearch( ints , index , ints.length , doubled );
    // If the doubled value is found, remember it.
    if ( position >= 0 ) { doubledNumbers.add( ints[ position ] ); }
    // Prepare for next loop.
    index++;
}
System.out.println( "doubledNumbers: " + doubledNumbers.toString() );
```

When run.

> array = [2, 3, 9, 12, 7, 18]
>
> doubledNumbers: [18]

By the way, I thought about using a [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html) such as [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html). But after a quick look at the [*OpenJDK* version 14 source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk14/file/6c954123ee8d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/TreeSet.java), the `contains` method seems to use an iterator through all elements with no optimization taking advantage of the keys being maintained in a sorted order.

Comment: Hello @Basil! Thanks for the solution, it is really a nice approach (+1). In my other exercises binary search will definitely be useful for me. However, in my case now I want to solve the problem using only arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed what I wanted to approach in my question but everybody was very helpful so I don't know which answer should I accept :)

```
Random random = new Random();

int[] array = new int[50];
int[] newArray;
int evenNumber;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = random.nextInt(200);
    System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
}
newArray = new int[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
        evenNumber = array[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] * 2 == evenNumber) {
                evenNumber = i;
                System.out.println("The searched numbers: " + array[evenNumber]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```